# Finding a TOP LEVEL parent in Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have got two tables as following

Table Person

```
  Id   Name
   1    A
   2    B
   3    C
   4    D
   5    E
```

Table RelationHierarchy

```
ParentId   CHildId
   2         1
   3         2
   4         3
```

This will form a tree like structure

```
      D
      |
      C
      |
      B
      |
      A
```

ParentId and ChildId are foreign keys of Id column of Person Table

Let's suppose to EF entity Names are as Table names. I need to find top level Parent of Each  person. Resultset should be as following

```
 PersonId PersonName TopLevelPArentID TopLevelPArentName
```

Can anyone suggest any LINQ or LINQ to Entity Query?

Comment: I think you need to bring all data into memory and build tree. EF will not search for parents recursively. How would you implement it in plain SQL?

Comment: Does that mean i need to do .ToList on GetRelationHierarchy() method? e.g. context.RelationHierarchy.ToList(); and i need to apply logic to that data

Answer (score 0):

The top parent would have ParentId set to NULL I assume?
Using that assumption we can go through each Person using a recursive function.

```
public YourMainFunction(){
    List<Person> allPersons = entityContext.Person.ToList();
    List<KeyValuePair<Person, Person>> personAndParents = new List<KeyValuePair<Person, Person>>();
    foreach(Person p in allPersons){
        personAndParents.Add(new KeyValuePair<Person, Person>(p, GetTopParent(p)));
    }
}
//Now you have a list of each Persons Parents in a key/value pair list.

public Person GetTopParent(Person p){
    if(p.RelationHierarchy.Count(r=>r.ParentId != null) == 0){
        return p;
    }
    else{
        return GetTopParent(p.RelationHierarchy.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.ParentId != null).Person1); //This should be the parent relation, not the child relation, im not sure what you have named the relations.
    }
}
```

Comment: Top level parent won't have any row in Hierarchy table Parent Child relation i-e There will be no row where Top level parent of a Person is in ChildId column

Comment: Shouldn't it be a Recursive call?

Comment: I have made some edits, now using the RelationHierarchy table.
Foreach person check if it has a Parent in RelationHierarchy table. If not it is a parent, otherwise check the RelationHierarchy.Parent and so on. Its recursive since, GetTopParent is calling itself.